# Kendo Grid - How to disable rectangle selection in grid?

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid, drag-to-select

How to disable rectangle selection in grid? but i still want to use (shift/ctrl) key selection.

Comment: what do you mean by  rectangle selection ? Do you want to hide selection color and still want to select?(i.e do you want to select records without selection color?)

Comment: i just got the answer.

      function onDataBound(e) {
          this.selectable.userEvents._events.move = null;
      }


thank alot all